# Finding Transformation inverse

Tags: linear-algebra

For the following question I need to determine if the transformation is one-to-one.
Let $V$ be the vector space $C^1[0,1]$ and let $T:V \rightarrow R$ be defined by

$$T(\textbf f) = f(0) + 2f'(0) +3f'(1)$$

I know that for a transformation to be one-to-one the kernel has to be {$0$}. The answer says it is not one-to-one, so would I just try to find a function that $\neq$ $0$ that is in the kernel? Also would it be possible to find the transformation matrix given the above transformation?

Comment: Note that $T(x-5)=0.$

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you just need to find some $f \in V$ such that $f$ is not the zero function but

$$T(\mathbf{f}) = f(0) + 2f'(0) + 3f'(1) = 0$$

Not sure what `transformation matrix` means in terms of function transformations.

Comment: Is there a straight forward way to find that function without guess and check? I was told every linear transformation can be expressed as a matrix multiplication, so wondering if I can find that matrix

Comment: @lllll this is only true about linear transformations from $\mathbb{R}^m$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$, you are transforming a function space.